# OAuth - Python android app which can upload data to a server

Tags: android, python, linux, csv, oauth

So I have a kivy app which asks the user some questions and then takes the responses and exports them to a .csv file.

Now, the functionality I want to implement is that the user of the app should be given a token from my server and then the app should be able to use that token to upload the .csv file to the server. When uploading, the server should be able to identify the user based on the token given to the app.

I have no idea on how to implement this using python. Can someone point me to tutorials or something that do something along those lines? I have a Linux/Debian server with just apache installed.